# Failed Attempts Tracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, authentication

I am trying to track my login attempts but its only ever staying at one I need keep a running track of failed login attempts probably something simple wrong with my execution here.

```
 public int validateUser(string username, string userPassword)
   {
     var _currentUser = _db.users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.username == username);
      int _loginAttempts = =0;
       if (_currentUser != null)
       {

           if (isEncryptionEnabled == true)
           {

               string descriptedPassword = encrypt.DecryptRijndael(_currentUser.password, _currentUser.salt.ToString());

               if (descriptedPassword == userPassword)
                   return 0;
               else
                   _loginAttempts++;


           }
           else
           {
               var _unecryptedUser = _db.users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.username == username && a.password == userPassword);

               if (_unecryptedUser != null)
                   return 0;//zero represents sufcessfull login attempts

               return _loginAttempts++; // if anything greater zero is a failed login attempt send it back.
           }
       }
       return _loginAttempts;
   }
```

This is how the function is being called a button click of Login.aspx this is a webforms application.

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBContext _db = new DBContext();


        int canILogin = _db.validateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);

        if (canILogin == 0)// if i can loging after checking the encripted password then lets go to default page

            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        else
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx?attempt=" + canILogin.ToString());

        if (Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["attempt"]) > 0)
        {
            lblFailed.Text = "Failed Login Attempts"+ canILogin.ToString(); 
            lblFailed.Visible = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You're resetting `_loginAttempts` every time `validateUser` is called, because you wrote `int _loginAttempts = =0;` early in that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grovesNL is correct. Move your declaration for_loginAttempts outside the method. Try declaring it in the parent class. Like this:

```
class DBContext
{
    private int _loginAttempts = 0; // I assume private to keep from exposing it for security

    public int validateUser(string username, string userPassword)
    {
        // some code to test userPassword and increase or reset counter as needed
    }

    // more methods etc.
}
```